# What happens when assign new struct to array in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management, data-structures, struct

Say I have a C# struct:

```
struct Foo{
    int mA;
    public int A {get {return mA;}}
    int mB;
    public int B {get {return mB;}}

    public Foo(int a, int b)
    {
        mA = a;
        mB = b;
    }
}
```

And then I create and array of Foo's:

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[10];
```

What happens when I do this?

```
foos[1] = new Foo(20, 10);
```

If Foo was a class, the Foo[] would hold a pointer to a Foo object on the heap, and that pointer would be changed to the new Foo object (the old one being left for recycling).

But since structs are value types, would the new Foo(20, 10) just physically overwrite the same memory location previously held by foos[1]?

Comment: As far as I remember, yes. Structs are value-types, so instead of overwriting the reference at foos[i] (as you would see with a class), you're overwriting the whole struct at that position in the array. The garbage collector won't have to clean up the struct as it was physically overwritten. To test, calculate the size of an array of Foo when Foo is declared as a `struct` and when it is declared as a `class`, theoretically, the size should be `nElements * IntPtr.Size` for classes and `nElements * sizeof(Foo)` for structs; but I've never tried this in C# so I could be wrong.

Comment: I wish you could somehow make it so the `new` will actually override a Foo object directly, instead of creating and then copying.

Comment: @Yorye I think it would be about the same as the statement long i = 1 + 2;  The value 3 is created from the expression (1+2) and then copied into i.  So really, it's no different from how C style languages normally behave.

Comment: @Yorye: Eliminating that copy is the responsibility of the optimizer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice the memory associated with the relevant array slot is populated by the values. Given your code a small example shows what goes on. Please see comments inline. This is for a release build.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo[] foos = new Foo[10];
    foos[1] = new Foo(127, 255);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The code above is JIT compiled as follows

```
// Method setup
00280050 55              push    ebp
00280051 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
00280053 56              push    esi

// Create instance of Foo[]
00280054 b98a141d00      mov     ecx,1D148Ah
00280059 ba0a000000      mov     edx,0Ah
0028005e e8b121f4ff      call    CORINFO_HELP_NEWARR_1_VC (001c2214)
00280063 8bd0            mov     edx,eax

// Array range check 
00280065 837a0401        cmp     dword ptr [edx+4],1
00280069 7624            jbe     

// Assign foos[1] = new Foo(127, 255)  
0028006b 8d4210          lea     eax,[edx+10h]  <-- load location of foos[1] in eax
0028006e ba7f000000      mov     edx,7Fh        <-- load 127 in edx
00280073 beff000000      mov     esi,0FFh       <-- load 255 in esi
00280078 8910            mov     dword ptr [eax],edx    <-- move the value 127 to foos[1]
0028007a 897004          mov     dword ptr [eax+4],esi  <-- move the value 255 to foos[1] + offset

// This is just for the Console.ReadLine() part + rest of Main
0028007d e8d2436305      call    mscorlib_ni!System.Console.get_In() (058b4454)
00280082 8bc8            mov     ecx,eax
00280084 8b01            mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx]
00280086 8b402c          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+2Ch]
00280089 ff501c          call    dword ptr [eax+1Ch]

// Epilog
0028008c 5e              pop     esi
0028008d 5d              pop     ebp
0028008e c3              ret

//Exception handling
0028008f e8f05e7f70      call    clr!JIT_RngChkFail (70a75f84)
00280094 cc              int     3
```

So in short, the code loads the constants in registers and then copies values of these registers to the memory associated with the relevant part of the array instance.

Answer (score 1):

`foos[1]` will contain bit-wise copy of `new Foo(20, 10);`.

Comment: so the expression (new Foo(20, 10)) evaluates to the value and then it is copied into the location foos[1]?

Comment: Yes. Brian Rasmussen's answer shows what happens deep inside code.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of struct creates in each slot a default-value instance.  In C#, calling `new` on a struct in C# creates a new temporary instance (most likely on the stack) and assigning one struct to another always mutates the latter instance by overwriting all the fields of the latter with the contents of the corresponding fields in the former.  Thus, the statement
`foos[1] = new Foo(20,10);` creates a new temporary instance of `Foo` with default values, passes that instance to the parameterized constructor, copies all of the fields of that temporary instance to the instance held in array slot 1, and then discards the temporary instance.

Incidentally, the behavior of the corresponding statement in vb.net is slightly different.  Saying `foos(1) = New Foo(20,10)` will reset all the fields of `foos(1)` to their default values, and then pass `foos(1)` to the parameterized constructor.  This difference may be significant if any code tries to access `foos(1)` while the constructor is running.